# REST API design for endpoint with notification

Tags: api, rest

I am creating an API endpoint which takes a customer order, create the order and send email notification. At our current design once we successfully create the order, we send a success notification 201 to client and then make a call for our internal email api. Upon getting success notification from us the client app shows users a message to check his/her email.

I don't feel comfortable with this design because if for some reason the email sending method failed there are no way for client to understand this. On the other hand if we wait for to successfully the send the email and then send client app success notification it takes longer times.

So what is the right approach for overcoming this problem?

Comment: Does your internal email API fail so frequently this is a concern?

Comment: Your current design seems correct to me as long as the message is something like 'look for an email from us soon' -- you have essentially no control over the speed of email delivery.

Comment: @ceejayoz it doesn't fail but can we assume it is not going to fail? As we are giving order summary through email it is very important that our user receive the email properly.

Comment: If you want until you have successfully passed the email to your API, that still doesn't mean the email is going to be delivered soon or even at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your design works. Why would the client care if the mail service is not working? If the order passes all validations on the server and is persisted I would treat that as a successful state and return `201 Created`.

When the client gets 201 Created, then do what you say; give the user a message about checking their mail, but tell them that they should have some patience. Something like:

> Your order was submitted. Please check your mail. If you haven't got a mail in 24 hours please contact us, "or whatever other solution here".

You have no control on what time the mail will arrive at the users mail box anyway since mail sending is not a synchronous process.

*Remember: Seperate your conserns.*

Comment: I was thinking of using 202 but I think it is even more confusing because in that case client just know the order has been accepted but it can't even tell whether it has been created or not.

Comment: I this case 201 is the way to go.  This answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

`202 Accepted` would usually be the most appropriate response for a request which requires further processing. In your case, however, this might not be right because the email is not fundamental to the resource creation.

`201 Created` is perfectly acceptable for you because the order has actually been created. However, as the spec says, you *should* return a `Location` header with the URI of the created resource and an entity describing how to access the resource. That should get around your issue with a mail service failure - the client can still access their order and, to be honest, e-mail is not guaranteed delivery so I'm hoping that the email isn't an absolutely required part of your business process.